# Enhancing the plots from another person's research paper

Tags: thesis

I get some plots for comparision of different network simulation software. I need to include them in my thesis to provide details about the tool. The problem is that these plots are not of very good resolution and I want to enhance them. Although I must provide the reference of the paper and I downloaded these plots from IEEE library, I am not satisfied with the resolution.

Can anybody please tell me the method to enhance plots. I am including one plot as image here:- [image]

Comment: Do you have access to the data used to generate the plots? Anyway, this is probably more suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a technical problem with computer graphics.

Comment: Generate pdf, not bmp or jpg.

Comment: I agree raw data would be the best option. But if that's not possible look for the keywords ['digitize plot'](http://www.google.com/search?q=digitize+plot) - there is a number of nice tools around. Of course you understand the precision is then defined by the quality of the plot.

Comment: What I have done before is to [write on the image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/8141), so that labels will be consistent.  For the legend, you can use the tikz spy node to grab the legend image, repeat and enlarge them along with manual labels.  Remains the actual lines and labels but they don't look too bad to me in this example (I have seen far, far worse graphics).

Comment: I think that this question seems to be duplicate of the following questions, not the one which is now closed for. [I'd like to use a figure from a paper, what's the best way to do this?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/id-like-to-use-a-figure-from-a-paper-whats-the-best-way-to-do-this); [Software for extracting data from a graph without having to click on every single point?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/software-for-extracting-data-from-a-graph-without-having-to-click-on-every-singl)

Comment: I am voting to reopen as the OP's question is not about asking raw data from the authors of the original paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these Comments. I really found a lot of information here.

Comment: use these :   http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/
http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/
@Peter

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like how they have plotted the data, or there isn't sufficient resolution in their graphic (e.g., they used a PNG rather than PDF so that blowing up the document doesn't help resolution) then the only real solution is to ask the authors for a copy of their data, as suggested in the comments above.

You also may consider that if this does not work, the ugliness of their figure is not your responsibility: really, you are only including it as a courtesy to the reader, in order to make your document more self-contained.